# Codeigniter ajax request fail on output

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm trying to make an ajax request with jquery/codeigniter. Well, there seems to be a problem. i do get it to work, but it seems like the POST is not sent, for some reason...

Javascript

```
    $('#profileUpdateButton').click(function() {

        $.ajax({ // Starter Ajax Call

            method: "POST", 
            url: baseurl + 'profile/statusUpdate', 
            data: $('#statusUpdateForm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) { 
                alert(data);
            }

        });

        return false;

    });
```

From the codeigniter controller

```
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        echo $this->input->post('profileUpdate');
    }
```

If i replace the "echo $this->" etc.. with just echo "Hello" i do get an alertbox with "Hello", why don't i get the text from the box?

html

```
    <div id="statusUpdate">
        <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'profile/statusUpdate', array('name' => 'statusUpdateForm')); ?>
            <input type="text" value="Hva tenker du på?" name="profileUpdate" id="profileUpdate" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Hva tenker du på?')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Hva tenker du på?'" />
            <input type="submit" value="" name="profileUpdateButton" id="profileUpdateButton" />
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried to alert $('#statusUpdateForm').serialize() into the click event handler?

Comment: What happened when you ran `var_dump($_POST)`? Should be one of your your default debugging tools: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: if i var_dump i get array(0){} and alert $('#statusUpdateForm').serialize() give me http://prntscr.com/2ecwh

Answer (score 2):

Change your html markup to this...

```
<div id="statusUpdate">                   <!-- Use ID not NAME here |v| -->
    <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'profile/statusUpdate', array('id' => 'statusUpdateForm')); ?>
        <input type="text" value="Hva tenker du på?" name="profileUpdate" id="profileUpdate" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Hva tenker du på?')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Hva tenker du på?'" />
        <input type="submit" value="" name="profileUpdateButton" id="profileUpdateButton" />
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

you were setting the form's **name** and you were selecting `$('#statusUpdateForm')` which means the **id** of statusUpdateForm, not the name attribute...